# Unable to package Flow with scheduled path

Tags: managed-package, visual-workflow, 2gp, scheduled-flow

We are trying to add a `Flow` to a `2GP Managed Package`

the `Flow` has a scheduled action.

When we run the command:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create ....
```

We get an error message:

```
ERROR running force:package:version:create:  MyFlow: field integrity 
exception: unknown (Before you can activate a flow that contains 
scheduled paths, specify the default workflow user in your org’s process 
automation settings. Then save your flow again and activate it.)
```

But we cannot include the `default workflow user` in the package, therefore, there is always a missing dependency.

How do we fix this? such that we can include the `Flow` in the package